# El diseño de la página se desarma en Chrome , pero funciona en Mozila y Microsoft Edge

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Estoy utilizando bootstrap, jquery, y mis css y js personalizados. La parte que falla es el footer , las letras no salen del color indicado en el CSS ni con la distribución, además se mezclan dos sections consecutivos que tengo justo encima del footer ( todo esto ocurre solo en Chrome ) , les dejo el código adjunto

```
<footer class="footer-distributed">

  <div class="footer-left">

    <h3>LOGO</h3>

    <p class="footer-links">
      <a href="#">Inicio</a>
      ·
      <a href="#">Servicios</a>
      ·
      <a href="#">Productos</a>
      ·
      <a href="#">Contacto</a>
      ·

    </p>

    <p class="footer-company-name">Nombre de compañia &copy; 2017</p>
  </div>

  <div class="footer-center">

    <div>
      <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
      <p><span>Direccion</span> Ciudad, País</p>
    </div>

    <div>
      <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
      <p>+1 555 123456</p>
    </div>

    <div>
      <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
      <p><a href="mailto:support@company.com">support@example.com</a></p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="footer-right">

    <p class="footer-company-about">
      <span><a href="#">TRABAJEMOS JUNTOS</a></span>

    </p>

    <div class="footer-icons">

      <h4 style="color:white;">Nuestras redes : </h4>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>


    </div>

  </div>

</footer>
```

Y el CSS:

```
.footer-distributed{
  background-color: #292c2f;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  font: bold 16px sans-serif;

  padding: 55px 50px;
  margin-top: 80px;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-left,
.footer-distributed .footer-center,
.footer-distributed .footer-right{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

/* Footer left */

.footer-distributed .footer-left{
  width: 40%;
}

/* The company logo */

.footer-distributed h3{
  color:  white;
  font: normal 36px 'Cookie', cursive;
  margin: 0;
}

.footer-distributed h3 span{
  color:  #5383d3;
}

/* Footer links */

.footer-distributed .footer-links{
  color:  #ffffff;
  margin: 20px 0 12px;
  padding: 0;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-links a{
  display:inline-block;
  line-height: 1.8;
  text-decoration: none;
  color:  inherit;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-company-name{
  color:  #8f9296;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Footer Center */

.footer-distributed .footer-center{
  width: 35%;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center i{
  background-color:  #33383b;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 25px;
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 42px;
  margin: 10px 15px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center i.fa-envelope{
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 38px;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center p{
  display: inline-block;
  color: #ffffff;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin:0;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center p span{
  display:block;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size:14px;
  line-height:2;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center p a{
  color:  #5383d3;
  text-decoration: none;;
}


/* Footer Right */

.footer-distributed .footer-right{
  width: 20%;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-company-about{
  line-height: 20px;
  color:  #92999f;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-company-about span{
  display: block;
  color:  #ffffff;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-icons{
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-icons a{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color:  #33383b;
  border-radius: 2px;

  font-size: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 35px;

  margin-right: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

/* If you don't want the footer to be responsive, remove these media queries */

@media (max-width: 880px) {

  .footer-distributed{
    font: bold 14px sans-serif;
  }

  .footer-distributed .footer-left,
  .footer-distributed .footer-center,
  .footer-distributed .footer-right{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .footer-distributed .footer-center i{
    margin-left: 0;
  }

}
```

Comment: Usando tú codígo yo lo veo igual en Firefox y Chrome. ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo que reproduzca el problema?

Comment: Tienes razón , usando solo lo que mostré si funciona.El problema se presenta cuando lo mezclo con el resto del código de mi proyecto , pero lo raro es que solo se ve afectado en Google Chrome :/

Comment: Puede ser alguna etiqueta mal cerrada o algo así pero sin poder verlo es imposible saberlo